# Interface Builder Add IBAction and Segue a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, segue, ibaction

Is there anyway to add an IBAction and a segue to one UIBarButtonItem?

I tried adding a segue and IBAction, within Interface Builder, to a UIBarButtonItem that is within a UINavigiationController but only the segue worked fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is create a segue from the view controller to the next view controller and give it an identifier. Then add a target/action to your UIBarButtonItem, and at the end of the action method, call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier" sender:self]`.